# ListView doesn't listen to onClick

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm trying to do a ListView that it can refresh when i call the function actualizarDisplay().
I've seen in the log cat a message, and i have doubts abaout that message:

```
10-06 12:24:02.524: I/dalvikvm(6911): Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
10-06 12:24:02.524: W/dalvikvm(6911): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 561: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
10-06 12:24:02.524: D/dalvikvm(6911): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
10-06 12:24:02.688: D/AbsListView(6911): Get MotionRecognitionManager
10-06 12:24:02.712: D/AbsListView(6911): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
10-06 12:24:02.712: D/AbsListView(6911): unregisterIRListener() is called 
10-06 12:24:02.712: D/AbsListView(6911): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
10-06 12:24:03.055: D/AbsListView(6911): unregisterIRListener() is called
```

my problem is when i push the screen the event onClickListener is not reviced.

This is my main activity:

```
public class Rescate extends ActionBarActivity {

ArrayList<Ficha> listaFichas = new ArrayList<Ficha>();
MyCustomAdapter dataAdapter = null;

Ficha fichaAux = new Ficha();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rescate);

    Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    int tipo=b.getInt("lugar");

    switch(tipo) {
        case 1:
            break;

        case 2:
            break;

        case 3:
            break;

        case 4:
            fichaAux.setNumInv("1");
            fichaAux.setIden("cuadro");
            fichaAux.setUbi("sacrsitía");
            fichaAux.setNumHom(2);
            fichaAux.setMat("Plástico");
            fichaAux.setEstado(0);
            fichaAux.setPrioridad(1);
            listaFichas.add(fichaAux);

            fichaAux = new Ficha();
            fichaAux.setNumInv("2");
            fichaAux.setIden("cuadro");
            fichaAux.setUbi("sacrsitía");
            fichaAux.setNumHom(2);
            fichaAux.setMat("Plástico");
            fichaAux.setEstado(0);
            fichaAux.setPrioridad(2);
            listaFichas.add(fichaAux);

            actualizarDisplay();
            break;

         default:
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_rescate);
    }
}
```

this is my function actualizarDisplay which implements the lsiteners:

```
public void actualizarDisplay()
    {       
        dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this,R.layout.listadofichas, listaFichas);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listaObras);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
            {           
                Intent passIntent = new Intent();
                passIntent.setClass(Rescate.this, VistaFicha.class);

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putCharSequence("num",listaFichas.get(arg2).getNumInv() );
                bundle.putCharSequence("ubicacion",listaFichas.get(arg2).getUbi() );

                passIntent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(passIntent);
            }
        });

        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() 
        {
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, final int arg2, long arg3)
            {
                final String[] opciones = new String[] { "Si", "No"};
                final AlertDialog.Builder dialogo = new AlertDialog.Builder(Rescate.this);
                dialogo.setCancelable(true);
                dialogo.setTitle("¿Desea establecer que la obra ha sido rescatada?");
                dialogo.setItems(opciones, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                        if (item == 0)
                        {
                            listaFichas.get(arg2).setEstado(1);  
                            actualizarDisplay();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            listaFichas.get(arg2).setEstado(0);
                            actualizarDisplay();
                        }
                    }
                    });

                dialogo.setCancelable(false);
                dialogo.create();
                dialogo.show(); 


                return false;

            }
        });

        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }
```

and this are my functions to handle the ListView:

```
public class FichaAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
    {
        private ArrayList<Ficha> fichas;

        public FichaAdapter(ArrayList<Ficha> fichas) 
        {
            this.fichas = fichas;

            //Cada vez que cambiamos los elementos debemos noficarlo
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public int getCount() 
        {
            return fichas.size();
        }


        public Object getItem(int position) 
        {
            return fichas.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) 
        {
            return 0;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            FichaView view;
            if (convertView == null) //NO existe, creamos uno
                view = new FichaView(parent.getContext());
            else                    //Existe, reutilizamos
                view = (FichaView) convertView;

            view.setFicha(fichas.get(position));

            return view;
        }
    }

private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Ficha> 
    {

        private ArrayList<Ficha> fichaList;

        public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,ArrayList<Ficha> fichaList) 
        {
            super(context, textViewResourceId,fichaList);
            this.fichaList = new ArrayList<Ficha>();
            this.fichaList.addAll(fichaList);
        }


        private class ViewHolder 
        {
           TextView num,iden,ubi,hombres,material;
           ImageView foto;   
           RelativeLayout fondo;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            ViewHolder holder = null;

            if (convertView == null) 
            {
               LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
               convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.listadofichas, null);

              holder = new ViewHolder();
               holder.num = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.numInvResCon);
               holder.iden = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.idenRescCont);
               holder.ubi = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ubiResCon);
               holder.hombres = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.numHomResCon);
               holder.material = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.matRescCon);
               holder.foto = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imaResc);      
               holder.fondo = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fondoRes);
               convertView.setTag(holder);
           }
           else 
           {
               holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
           }

           Ficha ficha = fichaList.get(position);
           holder.num.setText(ficha.getNumInv());
           holder.iden.setText(ficha.getIden());
           holder.ubi.setText(ficha.getUbi());
           holder.hombres.setText(String.valueOf(ficha.getNumHom()));
           holder.material.setText(ficha.getMat());            

           if(ficha.getPrioridad()==1)
           {
               holder.num.setTextColor(Color.RED);
               holder.iden.setTextColor(Color.RED);
               holder.ubi.setTextColor(Color.RED);
               holder.hombres.setTextColor(Color.RED);
               holder.material.setTextColor(Color.RED);
           }

           if(ficha.getPrioridad()==2)
           {
               holder.num.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF8000"));
               holder.iden.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF8000"));
               holder.ubi.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF8000"));
               holder.hombres.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF8000"));
               holder.material.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF8000"));
           }

           if(ficha.getPrioridad()==3)
           {
               holder.num.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
               holder.iden.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
               holder.ubi.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
               holder.hombres.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
               holder.material.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
           }

           if(ficha.getEstado()== 1)
           {
               holder.fondo.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
               holder.num.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
               holder.iden.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
               holder.ubi.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
               holder.hombres.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
               holder.material.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
           }


           return convertView;

        }    
    }
```

I think the prgoblem is when the log cat says visibility: 0
I have a warning in this line:

```
convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.listadofichas, null);
```

i think that the problem is here.

i write the layouts:

listadofichas.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fondoRes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:contentDescription="@string/par" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imaResc"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/vacia"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/numInv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imaResc"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imaResc"
            android:text="@string/numInvResc"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="@dimen/letrasPequenasAumen" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/idenResc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/numInv"
            android:layout_below="@+id/numInv"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:text="@string/idenResc"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="@dimen/letrasPequenasAumen" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ubiResc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/idenResc"
            android:layout_below="@+id/idenResc"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:text="@string/ubiResc"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="@dimen/letrasPequenasAumen" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/numHomResc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ubiResc"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ubiResc"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:text="@string/numHomResc"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="@dimen/letrasPequenasAumen" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/matResc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/numHomResc"
            android:layout_below="@+id/numHomResc"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:text="@string/matResc"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="@dimen/letrasPequenasAumen" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/numInvResCon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/idenResc"
            android:layout_marginLeft="84dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/numInv"
            android:text="@string/vacia"
            android:textSize="@dimen/letrasPequenasAumen" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/idenRescCont"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/idenResc"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/numInvResCon"
            android:text="@string/vacia"
            android:textSize="@dimen/letrasPequenasAumen" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ubiResCon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/numHomResc"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/idenRescCont"
            android:text="@string/vacia"
            android:textSize="@dimen/letrasPequenasAumen" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/numHomResCon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/matResc"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ubiResCon"
            android:text="@string/vacia"
            android:textSize="@dimen/letrasPequenasAumen" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/matRescCon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/matResc"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/matResc"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/numHomResCon"
            android:text="@string/vacia"
            android:textSize="@dimen/letrasPequenasAumen" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imaResc"
            android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imaResc"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imaResc"
            android:contentDescription="@string/guia"
            android:src="@drawable/barralat" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/matResc"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/barrahor" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            style="@style/mySpinnerItemStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:entries="@array/equipos" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/numInvResCon"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/numInvResCon"
            android:layout_marginLeft="203dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/numInvResCon"
            android:text="@string/equiposAsig"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="@dimen/letrasPequenasAumen" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            style="@style/mySpinnerItemStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
            android:entries="@array/equipos" />

    </RelativeLayout>

and the layout of the activity

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="app.gepv.Rescate" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" >

        <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listaObras"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        tools:listitem="@layout/listadofichas" >
    </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The adpater works well because i can change the color,.. but the listener doesn't work
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does your application force close with this ?

Comment: one thing which is likely to cause problems (maybe not **the** problem): you call "ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listaObras);" from inside your "actualizarDisplay()" method. This way, it can be garbage collected as soon as the method is finished. Why don't you make the listview a class variable?

Comment: @ChintanSoni thanks for you interest about my problem. The application doesn't force close, when i push on a item from the listView the event is not registered. U have a warning in this line `convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.listadofichas, null);` maybe the problem will be here

Comment: ok, after your (as of now :)  ) last edit I'm sure that's the problem!

Comment: @0X0nosugar do you think that the problem is in the line `convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.listadofichas, null);`? dou you know how i can solve it?

Comment: The warning probably has nothing to do with it, having null is valid. If you want to remove it you could change it to `convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.listadofichas, parent);`

Comment: @RobVoisey i change the line but in the log cat appears the same : `onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
D/AbsListView(6911): unregisterIRListener() is called`, is this normal?

Comment: Like i said, probably has nothing to do with it. Try changing `public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, ...)` to public void onItemClick(AdapterView<Ficha> arg0, ...)`

Comment: what is that "MotionRecognitionManager" which is mentioned in the Logcat? Could you tell us what it does? And when/ where are the log entries about visibility ( "D/AbsListView(6911)" ) written?

Comment: @0X0nosugar MotionRecognitionManager y don't know what is, i can tell you the fields wich apear in the log cat: LEVEL-> D, TAG-> AbsListView, the mistake is for this. i'm looking for any information about this but i haven't found anything. The log about visibility appears when the activity is created

Answer (score 1):

In onCreate of your activity you have a switch in which you initiate the Adapters only if the value tipo is 4, so if it is not, the listview has no adapter and will do nothing. You could either debug to see which value it gets or at least put the line

```
 Log.d("Rescate","tipo = "+tipo)
```

to see which value it has. To see if the onItemClick is called you could plug as the first line in onItemClick the line:

```
Log.d("Rescate","onItemClick")
```

And see if this appears in the Log when you click an item in the list.

I think the error might be related to the fact that `ActionBarActivity` is depreciated, you should use `AppCompatActivity`.

If it still doesnt work could you also post the layout files you use?

Comment: For whatever it's worth: I copied the code, simplified it by making "Ficha" a String (which of course made the view holder and the adpater code very small) and leaving out the switch-statement in the 'onCreate()'. One error in the 'getView()': IDE can't resolve 'getSystemService()'. OK, so let's make the LayoutInflater a class member of the adapter. Now it's working nicely both as an ActionBarActivity and an AppCompatActivity. Which means you may be on the right track with the switch statement.

Comment: @0X0nosugar sorry but i don't uderstand you very well ... the mistake is in the switch?

Comment: Maybe you could update the files in your post, so that I can also see the simplified version. We might get there hopefully

Comment: @user3808066 sorry for the later answer i've changed ActionBarActivity for AppCompatActivity but ir doesn't work. I've wrote the layout file

Comment: @0X0nosugar i've remuvoved the switch statement but it doesn't work. the logcat says the same message:

Comment: @user2070274 & user3808066 - ok, I'll post a new answer with my working sample.

Answer (score 1):

So here's my code with String list items instead of Ficha ones. I made 'Rescate.java' first extend `AppCompatActivity` and then `ActionBarActivity`, and it worked for both versions:

```
public class Rescate extends ActionBarActivity
{
ArrayList<String> listaFichas = new ArrayList<>();
MyCustomAdapter dataAdapter = null;

String fichaAux = "Hello";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // setting this up with Strings to keep things simple
    listaFichas.add("Hello");
    listaFichas.add("Hi there");
    actualizarDisplay();
}

public void actualizarDisplay()
{
    dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this,R.layout.listadofichas, listaFichas);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listaObras);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
        {
            Intent passIntent = new Intent();
            passIntent.setClass(Rescate.this, VistaFicha.class);

            startActivity(passIntent);
        }
    });

    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener()
    {
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, final int arg2, long arg3)
        {
            final String[] opciones = new String[]{"Si", "No"};
            final AlertDialog.Builder dialogo = new AlertDialog.Builder(Rescate.this);
            dialogo.setCancelable(true);
            dialogo.setTitle("¿Desea establecer que la obra ha sido rescatada?");
            dialogo.setItems(opciones, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item)
                {

                    if (item == 0)
                    {
                        actualizarDisplay();
                        Toast.makeText(Rescate.this, "item = 0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(Rescate.this, "item != 0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

            dialogo.setCancelable(false);
            dialogo.create();
            dialogo.show();

            return false;

        }
    });

    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}

}
```

'VistaFicha.java' is just a blank activity showing "Hello World".

I put the adpater in a separate file 'MyCustomAdapter.java'

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter
{

    private ArrayList<String> fichaList;
    private LayoutInflater vi;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,ArrayList<String> fichaList)
    {
        super(context, textViewResourceId,fichaList);
        this.fichaList = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.fichaList.addAll(fichaList);
        // I had to change the original code because my adapter is not an inner class:
        vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    private class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView num;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.listadofichas, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.num = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvHallo);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        String ficha = fichaList.get(position);
        holder.num.setText(ficha);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

The xml for the list rows is simply a `TextView` (R.id.tvHallo) inside a `LinearLayout` and my Rescate activity contains only the usual "Hello World" and the `ListView` (R.id.listaObras)

Hope this helps, and let me know if there are any questions :)

Comment: @user2070274 - please tell us: what was that about the switch statement I left out? wasn't that somehow important for your app?

Comment: in this moment i dont' use the switch statement, when my code works i'll use the switch statement or i'll lonking for other way to do the app